# Как из Python кода сделать apk файл, без kivy?

Tags: python-3.x

Есть только сам код, можно ли как-то превратить его в apk файл? (Программа с интерфейсом)

```
import pytube
from tkinter import *

tk = Tk()
tk.geometry("300x400")
tk.resizable(False, False)
tk["bg"] = '#9fa2a1'
tk.title('Youtube downloader')

frame = Frame(tk, width= 274, height = 300)
frame["bg"]= "white"
frame.place(x=15, y=10)

entry = Entry(tk, background='gray', foreground='white', width='42')
entry.place(x = 25, y = 15)

label = Label(tk, bg='white',text='Вставить ссылку можно только\nна английской раскладке!')
label.place(x=65 , y=40)

def link():
    a = entry.get()
    youtube = pytube.YouTube(a)
    video = youtube.streams.filter(progressive=True).desc().first()
    video.download()

btn = Button(tk, width=36,text='скачать', border = 0, command=link, bg='#5bc0de', relief="groove", outline=None, fg='white')
btn.place(x = 24, y = 280)




tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: В чем проблема использовать Java или Kotlin вместо Python?

Comment: в том что я их не учил, а на данный момент знаю более менее только Python)

Comment: Тогда учтите что Python не рекомендуется для разработки мобильных приложений. Лучше всего просто перейти на другой язык.

Comment: хорошо, буду иметь ввиду!